# query from two datepickers

Tags: android, sqlite, date

I have two simple DatePickers in my layout.

...

```
    <DatePicker
    android:id="@+id/dp1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

...

```
<DatePicker
    android:id="@+id/dp2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

...

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/bokdate"
    android:layout_width="62dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/ok" />
```

I would query my db for registers between first DatePicker date and second DatePicker date.

Dates are stored in my datebase with this format `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`, using `datetime('now', 'localtime')` SQLite function.

I've tried this code but doesn't work.

```
    DatePicker dp1 = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.dp1);
    DatePicker dp2 = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.dp2);

    Integer day1 = dp1.getDayOfMonth();
    Integer month1 = dp1.getMonth() + 1;
    Integer year1 = dp1.getYear();

    String s1 = "'" + year1.toString() + "-" + month1.toString() + "-"
            + day1.toString() + " 00:00:00'";

    Integer day2 = dp2.getDayOfMonth();
    Integer month2 = dp2.getMonth() + 1;
    Integer year2 = dp2.getYear();

    String s2 = "'" + year2.toString() + "-" + month2.toString() + "-"
            + day2.toString() + " 00:00:00'";

    final Button b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bokdate);

    b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(OtherDatesActivity.this,
                    ShowDateStatisticsActivity.class);
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("query",
                    "SELECT * FROM statistics WHERE date BETWEEN " + s1 + " AND "
                            + s2);
            intent.putExtras(bundle);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
```

I was trying to generate 2 String's similar to date format.
What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try 
"SELECT * FROM statistics WHERE date >= Datetime(" + s1 + ") AND  date <= Datetime(" + s2 +")" ?

Comment: Solved, we need to insert getDay(),getMonth... into button onclicklistener, then switch month to insert "01" instead of "1" in the query.